# Not getting expected output when calling PowerShell function from Azure PowerShell Task

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

Given:

- PowerShell 5.1
- Azure DevOps Server 2019

I'm trying to call my function directly from my Azure PowerShell Task Arguments, is this possible? I'm not getting any expected output.

```
param([String] $Name, [Int] $Age, [String] $Path)

Function Foo
{
    Param(
        [String]
        $Name
    ,
        [Int]
        $Age
    ,
        [string]
        $Path
    )
    Process
    {
        write-host "Hello World"
        If ("Tom","Dick","Jane" -NotContains $Name)
        {
            Throw "$($Name) is not a valid name! Please use Tom, Dick, Jane"
        }
        If ($age -lt 21 -OR $age -gt 65)
        {
            Throw "$($age) is not a between 21-65"
        }
        IF (-NOT (Test-Path $Path -PathType ‘Container’))
        {
            Throw "$($Path) is not a valid folder"
        }
        # All parameters are valid so New-stuff"
        write-host "New-Foo"
    }
}
```

[image]

## Update 3

[image]

## Update 2

[image]

## Update 1

[image]

Comment: Please add the code as code tags in your question

Comment: Updated OP with code tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute your script directly, it will simply *define* the `Foo` function, but never *call* it.

Place the following *after* the function definition in your script in order to invoke it with the arguments that the script itself received, using the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) via [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting), which allows you to pass arguments via a variable containing an array or hashtable of parameter values, which needs to be referenced with `@` rather than `$`:

```
Foo @args
```

---

The alternative would be not to invoke a *script file*, but a *piece of PowerShell code* (in PowerShell CLI terms, this means using the 
`-Command` parameter rather than `-File`), which would allow you to use `.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) to first load the function definition into the caller's scope, which then allows it to be called:

```
. "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_RodneyConsole1Repo/FunctionExample.ps1"
Foo -Name Rodney -Age 21 -Path ""
```

Comment: I updated OP with latest results. Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Rod, if you pass `"Tom", "21", ""`, you're passing a _3-element array_ as a _single argument_; to pass _3 separate arguments_ (positionally), separate them _with whitespace_: `"Tom" "21" ""`

Comment: Please see Update 2  in OP

Comment: @Rod, you still need `@args`, as shown in this answer, not `$args`.

Comment: Update 3 in OP added and I did change to @args

Comment: @Rod, that's an unrelated follow-up error; your argument-passing problem is now solved. The follow-up error suggests that your `.ps1` file is UTF-8 encoded, but _lacks a BOM_, which is required for _Windows PowerShell_ to interpret it correctly.

Comment: you're absolutely correct! Take a look at word Container in OP code. It is surrounded by special quotes, smh. Thanks for sticking with me.

Comment: @Rod, the technique is called splatting, and the answer already had a link to it, but I've added a brief explanation just now.

Comment: When I use ```Foo @args``` does this mean the variables aren't going to be global?

Comment: @Rod, splatting is a way of passing _arguments_ that bind to _parameters_. It doesn't define variables.